# Cannot read property 'det_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

i'm trying to access the property value of a query, however it says it can not read the det_id property, it follows the code:

```
    var detname_img = [];
    var sqlEdit = "INSERT INTO images_det SET ?";

    for(var k=0; k < object.det_img.length; k++){

        detname_img.push({
            name_img : object.det_img[k].name_img,
        });

        connection.query(sqlEdit,detname_img[k]);
    }

    console.log(detname_img);

    for(var i = 0; i < detname_img.length; i++){

        var getDet = ("SELECT det_id from images_det where name_img = '" + detname_img[i].name_img + " ' order by 1 desc limit 1");

        connection.query(getDet, function(erro,result){
            console.log(result[i].det_id);
        });

    }
```

My console.log(result):

```
[ RowDataPacket { det_id: 155 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { det_id: 156 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { det_id: 157 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { det_id: 158 } ]
```

Comment: if there is that error, then how are the values getting printed in your console log statement??

Comment: good question, i dont know why, but when i console.log(result) i get all values, but when i try to console.log(result[i].det_id) return 'Cannot read property 'det_id' of undefined'

Comment: i'm sorry, but since your connection.query is asynchronous, it is returning undefined

Comment: i'm using promise, this change something?

Comment: Did you see that, result is an array, and your console ouput confirms it. So maybe you should use result[0].det_id?

Comment: Yeah! This give me a light, I'll try to use this and come back here to tell you if it worked, thank you a lot

Comment: It did not work, but I was able to group the id's into an object, but I can not return it to the next .then () of the promise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't return a object in .then() Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483312/i-cant-return-a-object-in-then-promise)