# I can't return a object in .then() Promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I created an object of ids, however I can not access it outside of my for or in my next .then (), i make det as global variable, does anyone know where it is wrong?

```
.then(function(idHome){

    home_id = idHome;

    var detname_img = [];
    var sqlEdit = "INSERT INTO images_det SET ?";

    for(var k = 0; k < object.det_img.length; k++){

        detname_img.push({
            name_img : object.det_img[k].name_img,
        });

        connection.query(sqlEdit,detname_img[k]);
    }

    // console.log(detname_img);

    for(var i = 0; i < detname_img.length; i++){

        var getDet = ("SELECT det_id from images_det where name_img = '" + detname_img[i].name_img + " ' order by 1 desc limit 1");

        connection.query(getDet, function(erro, result){

            for(var k = 0; k < result.length; k++){

                det.push({
                    det_id : result[k].det_id
                });
                console.log(chalk.blue(det[0].det_id));
                return det;
            }
        });
    }        

});
```

Comment: You don't appear to be returning it anywhere...

Comment: I tried to do ''return det'' and .then(something) console.log(someting) but does not work

Comment: Your `return det` is inside an async callback.  That's not a return value from your `.then()` handler.  You have NO return value from that function.  Perhaps you need to read: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).

Comment: In addition, you should pretty much never use plain async callbacks inside a `.then()` handler for exactly this reason.  Use the promise interface on your database (or promisify individual calls yourself) and then you can just return the promise directly.

Comment: What is this doing: `connection.query(sqlEdit,detname_img[k]);` all by itself with no completion callback and no assignment of any result to anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) node mysql package you can get the inserted id from the [result](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row) of the insert statement.

Since that package does not seem to be aware of the existence of promises you can dust off the api with a wrapper that will return a promise:

```
//turn an insert query with callback function 
//  into a function returning a promise
const insertAsPromise = connection => args => 
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      //call connection query with variable amount of argument(s)
      //  using Function.prototype.apply
      connection.query.apply(connection,args.concat(
        //add the callback to the list of arguments, callback
        //  is the last argument
        (error, results, fields) =>
          (error)
            ? reject(error)
            : resolve([results,fields])
      ))
  );


const sqlEdit = "INSERT INTO images_det SET ?";
Promise.all(
  object.det_img.map(
    image=>//map magical/global object.det_img to promise
      insertAsPromise(connection)([sqlEdit,image.name_img])
      .then(//when promise resolves get the inserted id
        ([results,fields])=>
          results.insertId
      )
  )
)
.then(
  results=>console.log(results)//should log an array of id's
)
.catch(
  err=>console.error("something went wrong:",err)
)
```